# Adding +x years to every field of data type 'datetime'

Tags: t-sql, axapta, sql-server-2012, dynamics-ax-2012

I would like to take sample data for AX 2012 and add 3 years to every field of data type: datetime.

I know there is the dateadd function and I can update for every field individually, just not sure how to search through the db and find every field of type datetime and perform the update.

Maybe building a temporary table of all fields of that type?

I am very new to sql so please be gentle...

Comment: If you find an answer useful then please accept it.

Answer (score 5):

This will provide a separate `UPDATE` statement per column.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'
UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]))
 + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME([object_id]))
 + ' SET ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
 + ' = DATEADD(YEAR, 3, ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ');'
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE system_type_id = 61 
-- or maybe IN (40, 42, 43, 58, 61) if you want to handle all date types 
AND is_computed = 0
AND [object_id] IN 
(
  SELECT object_id FROM sys.tables
  WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY([object_id], 'IsMsShipped') = 0
);

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

You could probably do something trickier to make multi-column updates per table, in cases where tables have more than one datetime column, but for a one-off task like this the extra complexity doesn't seem worth the performance difference.

Comment: This will do what you asked, but I'd think very carefully before uncommenting the EXEC.  It seems unlikely to me that you *really* want to update every datetime column in the database that way.

Comment: @GilM that's exactly why I used `PRINT` first, however I do assume the requirement was formulated with at least some thought. It's also quite easy to undo if you realize it isn't what you wanted.

Comment: Right.  It wasn't a criticism of the script at all.  I just felt like adding an additional warning for the OP, to be sure that he *really* wants to apply this to *every* datetime column of *every* table.  And, it's only easy to undo if none of the tables get updated before trying to undo it.

Comment: Yep, and you could add filters as well to only include columns in tables of a certain schema, or that match a certain naming scheme, etc.

Comment: Good luck, but I suspect this will give "duplicate key" when dates are in a unique index.

Comment: @Jan huh? If you add 3 years to *every* datetime value in a table, you're not going to change cardinality at all. Not that you would have a unique index on a datetime column anyway, but what you've suggested makes no sense.

Comment: I haven't tried running this yet, but what I want to do is not apply to every datetime column of every table, just ones that have pre-existing data.  For ones that are blank I'd like them to be unchanged.

Comment: So I just tried to run... I get this error:Msg 4406, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Update or insert of view or function 'dbo.INVENTVALUEREPORTINDIRECTBALANCE' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.

Comment: @Andrew yep, you'll need to filter out computed columns (there is a column for that in sys.columns) and probably views too (since not all will be updatable).

Comment: Aaron, would I do that with the 'AND is_computed = 0' line? setting that to 1 for example?

Comment: @Andrew no, I just added that clause today to filter out computed columns. You want "is computed" to be false (0), not true (1), in order to *avoid* trying to update columns you can't.

Comment: OK, this works great, the only issue I'm having now is certain effectivity dates (which are set at the default value).  The default value is 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000.  I would like for this script to overlook these and not touch them.  I'm having trouble selecting fields to overlook because the script just looks for anything of type datatime and makes the updates accordingly.

Comment: @Andrew, just add a WHERE clause inside the string, e.g. `WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' > ''19000101'';'`